# How to get DIV index number based on click element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following HTML structure

```
<div id="preview-wrapper">
    <div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">
        <a class="rotate-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img class="rotate" src="public/assets/img/rotate.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">
        <a class="rotate-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img class="rotate" src="public/assets/img/rotate.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">
        <a class="rotate-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img class="rotate" src="public/assets/img/rotate.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">
        <a class="rotate-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img class="rotate" src="public/assets/img/rotate.png">
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview">
        <a class="rotate-a" href="javascript:void(0);">
            <img class="rotate" src="public/assets/img/rotate.png">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now If user click to image tag

`<img class="rotate" src="public/assets/img/rotate.png">`

Inside of this div(fourth number of div)

`<div class="dz-preview dz-image-preview"> ... </div>`

I want to find that `div` index number which user click his child img tag.

Hope you understand what I am looking for.

Any Idea how to find click div index number?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.index()](https://api.jquery.com/index)

```
var $dics = $('.dz-image-preview img').click(function(){
    var index = $(this).closest('.dz-image-preview').index()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on("click", "img.rotate", function () {
  // get parent div element, then use index() function
  alert(
    $($(this).parents("div.dz-image-preview")[0]).index()
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `index()` method to return the index position of specified elements relative to other specified elements.

```
$('a.rotate-a').click(function(){
  var divIndex = $(this).closest('.dz-preview').index('.dz-preview');
  alert(divIndex);
});
```

Note: If the element is not found, `index()` will return -1